# how do i delete all non filtered rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

if i have an excel sheet and i filter by a certain column, how do i then delete all non visible rows?

Comment: I think you'll probably have to do that in VBA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you have all your filters selected you can highlight what remains and then click:

Excel 2007:

```
Home>Editing>Find & Select>Go to special...>Visible Cells Only
```

Excel 2003:

```
Edit>Go To...>Special...>Visible Cells Only
```

Copy and paste into a new sheet.

Comment: Ctrl+G is the hotkey for "Go to..." in excel 2003

Comment: I couldn't find this in the newest version of Excel, but the answer here helped me: https://superuser.com/questions/387484/how-to-delete-rows-not-in-filter

Answer (score 2):

Reverse filter on what you don't need and delete those rows. All that will be left are the rows you need - Excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

A nice, quick technique: use the Fill Color icon to fill all the cells in one of the columns you see. Then do a color filter on that column, and delete all the rows. You will be left only with the filtered rows.