# Remove Rows Not Part of Filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2000

I am filtering a large Excel spreadsheet.  I want to remove all rows on the sheet that are not a part of the filter. I know I can copy the rows and paste them into another spreadsheet.  But I would rather apply the change directly to the same spreadsheet.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: While it is filtered, stick an arbitrary value in a helper column and copy down to all visible rows.  Unfilter and then filter on the helper column, selecting the blanks.  Delete all of the newly filtered rows.  Then remove the filter and delete the helper column.

Comment: @fixer1234 I think this qualifies as an answer (not a comment). Upvotes will be interpreted as "good answer"! instead of "good comment!"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i delete all non filtered rows in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/147740/how-do-i-delete-all-non-filtered-rows-in-excel)

Comment: @agtoever: I hadn't looked for duplicate questions when I posted the comment.  I agree with the duplicate you found, which would make this a duplicate of a duplicate.  Those are already full of good solutions, including one that sounds similar (but excludes the procedure).